# Marking Parameters as Nullable

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I've picked up some code from a colleague, and in one of his methods he has a boolean parameter: `ByVal showProactiveChases As Boolean?`. I had to look up the `?` operator yesterday to see that it denotes a Nullable type. My question is, if I change it to: `ByVal showProactiveChases As Nullable(Of Boolean)`, does the meaning remain the same? I think provided it doesn't change the meaning the second way is much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the meaning is exactly the same.

`Boolean?` and `Nullable(Of Boolean)` will be compiled to exactly the same IL.

(I personally find the first version more readable, but it's all down to personal taste.)

Answer (score 2):

[There's a third option too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx):

> The following example constructs a
>   nullable Boolean type and declares a
>   variable of that type. You can write
>   the declaration in three ways:
>
> ```
> Dim ridesBusToWork1? As Boolean
> Dim ridesBusToWork2 As Boolean?
> Dim ridesBusToWork3 As Nullable(Of Boolean)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the same.

? is the shorthand for `Nullable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ? operator is in fact a shortcut for Nullable or Nullable(Of T).